# How to display the contents from entry widget list?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have written a code where `Label` and `Entry` widgets' variables are put in a list (in order to avoid the number of lines which will take for creation of each `Label` and `Entry` widgets). Then a for loop to create `Label` and `Entry` widgets are used, A submit button is used which have to list the entries of each `Entry` widget. But an empty value is displayed instead of displaying the entered value. Can anyone help me to know the reason and correct the code.

Below is the code which I have written:

```
from Tkinter import *
app = Tk()

list1 = ['l1','l2','l3']
list2 = ['e1','e2','e3']

entries = []

r = 0
c = 0
for m,n in zip(list1, list2):
    x = Label(app, text=m)
    x.grid(row = r, column =c)

    n = StringVar()
    e = Entry(app, textvariable = n)
    e.grid(row =r , column = c+1)

    entries.append(e.get())
    r = r + 1



def func():
    entries.append("Dfg")
    print entries

s = Button(app, text = "Submit", command = func)
s.grid(row = r, columnspan=2)

app.minsize(400, 400)
app.mainloop()
```

Please note: There could be indentation problem while posting the code, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

The `for loop` is for initialize in this case, When the Entry is been created,The input of `Entry` is empty , so when you `entries.append(e.get())` got the empty
.I change something from your code , and the entries will be entered value when you click the button BTW I use python3 instead of python2

```
from tkinter import *
app = Tk()

list1 = ['l1','l2','l3']
list2 = ['e1','e2','e3']

entries = []
e = []
r = 0
c = 0
for index, m in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)):
    x = Label(app, text=m)
    x.grid(row = r, column =c)

    n = StringVar()
    e.append( Entry(app, textvariable = n))
    e[index].grid(row =r , column = c+1)
    r = r + 1

def func():
    entries = []
    for a in e:
      entries.append(a.get())
    print(entries)

s = Button(app, text = "Submit", command = func)
s.grid(row = r, columnspan=2)

app.minsize(400, 400)
app.mainloop()
```